# GNU make - making one task do another task as well

Tags: linux, makefile, dependencies, gnu-make

Here is my makefile:

```
z : a
    echo "REDOING Z" ; touch z

a : b b2
    touch a
    touch a2
    touch z # should disable z but doesn't

b : c c2
    touch b
    touch b2
```

When I do `make a`, `z` is touched twice, I want it to only be touched once, how do I do that?

Comment: What's the actual goal here? You want to have a target that sometimes generates a file that another target also generates and skip that other target when that happens? You want a target that generates two files that make understands correctly? Something else?

Comment: I have a target that sometimes generates a file that another target also generates and skip that other target when that happens, and I want to run efficiently instead of generating the second file twice (think that `touch z` is actually something that takes time)

Comment: I don't think you are going to have much luck getting make to handle "sometimes" outputs at all sanely. It isn't really designed for that. Not to mention that there are ordering problems here (what if make runs the `z` target before the `a` target in an instance where `a` will create `z`?).

Comment: @EtanReisner - Actually, it always outputs `z`, check out the explanation I gave below on the first answer.

Comment: So it *always* generates `z`? Then why do you have/need the separate `z` target? when does that run? Do the `a` and `z` file names share a pattern you can use with a make `%` wildcard?

Answer (score 1):

The targets and recipes are in disconnect here: the recipes should only produce its targets, not other targets. E.g.:

```
z : a
    touch z

a : b b2
    touch a

b : c c2
    touch b

# add rules for b2, c and c2
```

Comment: This is explicitly **not** an answer to the question that was asked.

Comment: The process of generating `a` can also generate `z` very efficiently using intermediate data from the creation of `a`. If I force a separation between the two then I am forced to work inefficiently. Note that I don't have a way to save the intermediate data into a file.

Comment: @tohava Then your rule must state that it generates multiple files. In GNU Make you cannot have rules that generate one or more files, only a fixed number.